# Power automate export table from Power BI to xlsx file

Tags: excel, powerbi, xlsx, powerbi-desktop, power-automate

I Have to export data from Power BI report to xlsx file.

This file will work as a import file for another system, so what I need is to create a xlxs file with mandatory data set ( Column names and data types ) and export it to Onedrive folder. System then automatically take the import and move it to the old import folder ( So any new xlsx file which will be in folder will be imported again).

After I did all of this manually, import works great. When I am trying this in Power automate, I am not able to export the file to xlsx instead of csv.

I Found some tutorials, but in all of them i have to create a excel template with column name same as in Power BI table first, what is not able because of system import logic.

Can someone help me with that ?

Thanks.